# Modify thermal trip points

Tags: overheating, command-line, temperature

Can you please instruct me on how to modify critical trip points. My computer keeps shutting down and my sensors are telling me that I am running hot when utilizing demanding programs. I am utilizing Ubuntu 12.10. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you can't modify the critical trip point - if you were to increase it to stop your machine shutting down then you risk damaging the silicon.  The sole reason for the critical trip point is to avoid permanent damage of the system due to thermal overrun.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old question, but...

Critical trip point is defined in BIOS and communicated to the OS via ACPI. Assuming the trip-point is set to some reasonable value and the OS is reading it correctly: maybe the computer is trying to tell you it's overheating.

Check to see if the fans (if any) are still working and the heatsink is not plugged up with dust. Failing that, you can try to get the CPU to run at a lower maximum speed. Research P-states: maybe Ubuntu has a a way to modify/limit those.